# jQuery - drag and drop between divs while being able to resize item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm having some issues implementing `resizable`, `draggable`, and `droppable` in jQuery-UI.

I have an item that should be able to be dragged and dropped between 2 divs. While inside a div, I want to be able to resize the item but constrain it to the current div that it is inside.

When I try adding a "containment: 'parent'" option to the resizable, I see a lot of odd results. Has anyone run into this?

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container1">
    <div class="widget1">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container2">
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
$('.widget1').resizable({
    containment: 'parent'
}).draggable({
    revert: 'invalid'
});

$('.container1, .container2').droppable({
    tolerance: 'fit
});
```

You can easily produce the issue in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/atb87z6s/1/

Drag the red square from the top blue container into the bottom blue container, and then try to resize the red square.

I think this has to do with the red item not becoming a child of the target blue div (instead, remaining a child of the top blue div).

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!

First, you need to make sure the containers have `position: relative`. The red item needs a `position: absolute`.

The droppable option needs a handler for the drop event:

```
$('.container1, .container2').droppable({
  tolerance: 'fit',
  drop(ev, ui) {
    const droppedTarget = $(this);
    const elem = ui.draggable.detach();

    elem.css({
        top: ui.offset.top - droppedTarget.offset().top,
        left: ui.offset.left - droppedTarget.offset().left 
    });

    elem.appendTo(droppedTarget);
  }
});
```

Link to updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/atb87z6s/2/